# Visual Studio Regex Find/Replace Wildcard

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am using the find/replace option in visual studio.

I have this:

```
new GeoState { Name = "Arizona", Abbreviation = "AZ", Country = "US" },
```

And want to change it to this:

```
new GeoState { Abbreviation = "AZ", Country = "US" },
```

For all occurrences of states in my file. Effectively removing the `Name` property.

The regex find/replace expression I am running is this:

Find:

```
new GeoState { Name = ".*",
```

Replace:

```
new GeoState {
```

However, in the example above, that finds the following:

```
new GeoState { Name = "Arizona", Abbreviation = "AZ",
```

changing it to this:

```
new GeoState { Country = "US" },
```

Why is `Abbreviation = "AZ",` included in the selection? It should terminate upon the first instance of `",` after the wildcard.

Comment: Does VS support the non-greedy form `Name = ".*?"` ? Does VS support negated character classes such as `Name = "[^"]*"` ?

Comment: More info on Visual Studio expressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is greedy: `".*",`

This matches the Name, but continues to `"AZ",` since that also matches. It stops there since `Abbreviation` is the last thing that ends with a comma.

To make it non-greedy use: `".*?"` The extra `?` means that it now matches zero or more characters, but *as few as possible*. So now when it encounters the first item with double-quotes that ends with a comma, it will correctly stop at `"Arizona",`.

Alternately, you could use `new GeoState { Name = "[^"]+",` - here the `[^"]+` part is a negative character class that will match any character that is not a double-quote, so it will correctly stop at the first set of closing double-quotes.